# JButton inside JMenuBar isn't tight-fitting

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jmenubar

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

It seems my green arrow button keeps making the `JMenuBar` taller than it should be, notice the space above and below the rest of the buttons. How do I stop it from doing this? I've tried making the `JButton` border/padding as small as possible, here is my code:

```
JButton runFlow;
runFlow = new JButton(IconHandler.getIcon(IconHandler.RUN_ICON));
runFlow.setOpaque(false);
runFlow.setContentAreaFilled(false);
runFlow.setBorder(null);
runFlow.setBorderPainted(false);
runFlow.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

Is it something to do with the menu bar format?

Comment: *"JButton inside JMenuBar isn't tight-fitting?"*  Buttons go better in a `JToolBar`.  But for 'snug fit' try `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` in a `JPanel`..

Comment: I agree with JButtons being better held in a JToolBar. In addtion, check your RUN_ICON. Does the picture contain further (transparent) pixels above and below the arrow we are seeing?

Comment: AFAIK there is BoxLayout, but hasn't something to do with Dimension from Icon

Comment: change the icon size to a smaller one like 16 x 16